# Javascript regular expression syntax error?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to evaluate a test string against a regular expression I build from a string extracted from a hidden input element, the code is as follows

```
HTML
<input type="hidden" name="reg_2" id="reg_2" value="^\\d{5}$">

JS
var regTest = new RegExp( $('#reg_2').val(), 'g' );
var valid = "12345";
var invalid = "47";
alert(regTest.test(valid));<--Returns false
```

It keeps evaluating to false, I'm not sure if the syntax is wrong or if there's something else I'm missing.  I tried with and without the global flag, and I also confirmed that the jQuery selector is returning the correct value.  Any help or insight is welcome.  Thank you.

UPDATE

Thank you for the prompt responses.  I was following the example on the [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) which shows a hardcoded string in the RegEx constructor with a double backslash and thought that's what I needed to pass to my script.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape the backslash. The value of the hidden input should just be `"^\d{5}$"`. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/PQsxV/).

Answer (score 2):

Remove one slash in the input value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="reg_2" id="reg_2" value="^\d{5}$">
```